# Loop through the array of strings and spit out into markup

Tags: json, call

I have an array of categories which has "category" and "entries". Entries has an array of coma separated strings. I am trying to loop through each category to populate a button (and it's working), but I cant figure out how to loop through each "entries" array full of strings and place each string into "li" element related to the "category".
 Would really use an advise.

Here is my CodePan gust to see what is happening.

```html
    $(function() {
  var healthTab = "https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/od09thh3aiwm/entries/?access_token=cc0fe7d7a6e85023656d817693d2aca605401c4cb3d967fc8df3dbe712b24ce4&select=fields.diseaseLongName,fields.diseaseCategory&content_type=disorder";
  
  $.getJSON( healthTab, function( data ) {  
    var diseaseEntries = data.items;
    var diseaseCategory = [];
    var diseasesGrouped = [];
    var markup = "";
    
    // Create a unique list of disease categories
    $.each(diseaseEntries, function (counter, val) {
      var thisDisease = diseaseEntries[counter].fields.diseaseCategory;
      if(!diseaseCategory.includes(thisDisease)){
        diseaseCategory.push(val.fields.diseaseCategory);
      }
    });
    
    // Sort that list alphabetically
    diseaseCategory.sort();
    
    // Add each category to an array so we can associate entries with it later
    $.each(diseaseCategory , function( counter, val){
      var disease = {};
      disease.category = diseaseCategory[counter];
      disease.entries = []; 
      diseasesGrouped.push(disease); 
     });
   
    
    // Add entries to diseasesGrouped based if their category matches
     $.each(diseaseEntries, function( counter, val){
       var currentCategory = diseaseEntries[counter].fields.diseaseCategory;
       var currentLongname = diseaseEntries[counter].fields.diseaseLongName;
       var myDiseaseIndex = null;
       
       for(var i= 0, l = diseasesGrouped.length; i< l; i++){
         if(diseasesGrouped[i].category === currentCategory ){
            myDiseaseIndex = i;
         }
       }
       
       // Push all the diseases that match the 
       diseasesGrouped[myDiseaseIndex].entries.push(currentLongname);
     }); 
    
    // Add all the full disease names within each category
    $.each(diseasesGrouped, function( counter, val){
     
      diseasesGrouped[counter].entries.sort();
      markup +="<div class='js-accordion' data-accordion-prefix-classes='breeds-list__alphabetic'>";
        markup +="<button class='js-accordion__header'>" +  diseasesGrouped[counter].category + "</button>";
          markup +="<div class='js-accordion__panel'>"
            markup +="<ul>";
              // spit out list
              $.each( diseasesGrouped, function( counter, val ) {
                
                markup +=diseasesGrouped[counter].entries;
                // $.each(diseasesGrouped[counter].entries, function(counter, val){
                //    markup +="<li class='list'>";
                //     markup +=diseasesGrouped[val];
                //    markup +="</li>";
                // });
                
              });
             
            markup +="</ul>";
          markup +="</div>";
        markup +="</div>";

      
    });
    $(".health-list").append(markup);
    console.log("diseasesGrouped");
    console.log(diseasesGrouped);
  });
  
  
  //   function enableAccordion() {
  //   $(document).on('click', '.js-accordion', function(){
  //     if($(this).hasClass('js-accordion--active')){
  //       $(this).removeClass('js-accordion--active');
  //     } else {
  //       $(this).addClass('js-accordion--active');
  //     }
  //   });
  // }
  
});
```